# xxx is not a function in my ViewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

why do I get a `Uncaught TypeError: this.createRow is not a function`
on the matrixLengthsAvailable array construction ?

The `createRow` function is declared at the end of my viewmodel...

```
function TabBuyHarvesterModel() {
    self = this;

    this.selectedEmote = ko.observable('kappa');
    this.matrixLengthsAvailable = ko.observableArray([
        { length: 10, pctDetails: this.createRow(10) /*ko.mapping.fromJS({ rowLength: 10 })*/ }
        //30,
        //60,
        //180,
        //360,
        //720,
            //1440
        ]);

    this.selectEmote = function (emoteClicked) {
        self.selectedEmote(emoteClicked.emote);
    };

    this.createRow = function (rowLength) {
        var ret = new TabBuyHarvesterMatrixRowModel();
        ret.rowLength(rowLength);
        return ret;
    };
}
```

Comment: `this` refer to the object `{ length: 10, pctDetails: this.createRow(10)}`, use the `self` (unless it's the context of observable array you are expecting, not familiar with knockout)

Comment: @gillesc I also tried `self` but get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use self, as already pointed out, and use it right, as in everywhere, and then you need to switch the order of the methods, so that createRow is defined before it is needed.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/oshmn46o/

```
function TabBuyHarvesterModel() {
var self = this;

self.createRow = function (rowLength) {
    var ret = new TabBuyHarvesterMatrixRowModel();
    ret.rowLength(rowLength);
    return ret;
};

self.selectedEmote = ko.observable('kappa');
self.matrixLengthsAvailable = ko.observableArray([
    { length: 10, pctDetails: self.createRow(10) /*ko.mapping.fromJS({ rowLength: 10 })*/ }
    //30,
    //60,
    //180,
    //360,
    //720,
        //1440
    ]);

self.selectEmote = function (emoteClicked) {
    self.selectedEmote(emoteClicked.emote);
};
```

}

Comment: There's no reason to use `self` *everywhere*. I've found that only using `self` when you *need* to makes the code more clear.

Comment: yes what is the reason to use `self` where `this` is working? I already find it silly to have to do `var self = this;` lol I'd try to avoid it if I could

Comment: The **only** place in this code where self might be needed is *inside* the `selectEmote` function. Depending on how it's called.

Answer (score 1):

since ko.observableArray() is a function the this reference in this.createRow will reference the obervableArray context, change this to self.

Comment: I also tried self and I get `self.createRow is not a function`

Comment: I think actually its because the function isn't defined yet. ko.observable() is being called right away, therefore trying to call createRow immediately. But since you have your function definitions within the constructor itself and not on the prototype, those functions have to be created each time you call the constructor.

Comment: either attach those function definitions to the prototype, or define them before the call to ko.observable

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the `createRow` function before it's been created. Define `createRow` **before** `matrixLengthsAvailable`. A better approach would be to define `createRow` on the `TabBuyHarvesterModel` prototype. This defines the function a single time, before your class is ever instantiated.

```
function TabBuyHarvesterModel() {
    ...
}

TabBuyHarvesterModel.prototype.createRow = function (rowLength) {
    var ret = new TabBuyHarvesterMatrixRowModel();
    ret.rowLength(rowLength);
    return ret;
};
```

Comment: thanks...dammit I thought about that but didn't bother trying because I deemed it would be a too ridiculous...

Answer (score 1):

If you only reference `createRow` from inside `TabBuyHarvesterModel`, then just making it a plain old function will work. Also, if you do this, then you will not have to define `createRow` before the `matrixLengthsAvailable` observable because JavaScript always hoists functions to the top of a closure even if they are not defined at the top of the closure:

```
function TabBuyHarvesterModel() {
    self = this;

    this.selectedEmote = ko.observable('kappa');
    this.matrixLengthsAvailable = ko.observableArray([
        { length: 10, pctDetails: createRow(10) /*ko.mapping.fromJS({ rowLength: 10 })*/ }
        //30,
        //60,
        //180,
        //360,
        //720,
            //1440
        ]);

    this.selectEmote = function (emoteClicked) {
        self.selectedEmote(emoteClicked.emote);
    };

    function createRow(rowLength) {
        var ret = new TabBuyHarvesterMatrixRowModel();
        ret.rowLength(rowLength);
        return ret;
    }
}
```